# Javascript databinding and templating with datasets

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, dataset

Is there any native way of doing data binding with HTML5 attributes and javascript?

I have seen:

- angular
- code project dataset - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30584/Javascript-Dataset-Data-Repeater-and-Grid
- Knockout

being used... but was wondering if there is a native way of doing it?

Bing / Google are not being so helpful with this one.

I was imagining something along the lines of this (Just some pseudo code but hoped it might help you to understand what I was asking for):

**HTML**

```
<ul id = "People"></ul>

<--Start:DataTemplate:List-->
    <li><!--Name--> is <--Age--></li>
<--End:DataTemplate-->
```

**JavaScript**

```
var data = {
    { Name: "James", Age: 25 }
    { Name: "Bob", Age: 55 }
}

var myList = new Templater();
myList.Bind( "List", data, "People" );

data.push( { Name: "Mike", Age: 45 } );
myList.Update();
```

Comment: There is no native way in javascript for templating and data binding. I've just stumbled upon this link : http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more. Seems pretty interesting.

Comment: Cool comparisons man, thanks for the find... you search king/queen you!